# enumerators implementation in c++

Tags: enumeration, c++03, enumerator

I know that enumeration type implementation depends on the values of enumerators, the compiler choose a type that can represent all enumerators value, in the example below I don't know why **example1** doesn't compile, whereas **example2** compile fine ?

**NOTE:**

That big number is not just a random number, it's exactly `pow(2,63)`, I couldn't use it there since enumerators can only be initialized with integral constant expressions.
`9223372036854775808 = pow(2,63)`

---

**example1.1:**

```
enum A{a=9223372036854775808,b=-1};

cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
```

Error:  no integral type can represent all of the enumerator values for 'main()::A'
**example1.2:**

```
enum A{a=9223372036854775808,b=-9223372036854775807};

cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
```

`b=-( pow(2,63) - 1 )`
This also gives me the same error that no integral type can represent all of the enumerator values for A.

---

**example2:**

```
enum A{a=9223372036854775808,b=-9223372036854775808};

cout << sizeof(a) << endl; // prints 8
```

This one compiles without any errors, and prints the sizeof(a) which is 8.

---

Is there any explaination for the above behaviour ?

---

**Update:**
If you are using [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) to compile the above code, it compiles without errors, because it has an integral type that is 16 bytes long, so changing the value of `a` to `pow(2,127)-1` and `b` to `-1` will give the same error again. to prevent confusion, let's stick with 32-bit machine for the sake of this example, for online compiler use [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qg50hZ).

My question is clear, why it works if `b=-9223372036854775808` , and it doesn't if `b=-1` ?

**Update2:**

Note that **example2**([c++11 comipler](http://ideone.com/fV1MGm)) doesn't compile using c++11, which in my opinion is the logical thing to do. but in c++03 **example2**([c++03 compiler](http://ideone.com/ayXb9M)) compiles fine, but **example1** doesn't compile.

Comment: Is `b` truncated in example2, or is it truly `-9223372036854775808`?

Comment: @woolstar I can't find any information about whether `b` value get truncated or not. I've updated my question, I tested this with c++11 and it doesn't compile both `example1` and `example2` which in my opinion is the correct behavior.
In c++03 `example2` compiles fine, which I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was compiling in C++11 mode, therefore being unable to reproduce the error. But now that I switched to [C++03 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/495f221f39229edd), I can reproduce the problems and the errors are different:

```
main.cpp:5:10: warning: integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default]

 enum A{a=170141183460469231731687303715884105727,b=-1};

          ^

main.cpp:5:1: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 [enabled by default]

 enum A{a=170141183460469231731687303715884105727,b=-1};

 ^

main.cpp:5:1: warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type [-Wlong-long]

main.cpp:5:54: error: no integral type can represent all of the enumerator values for 'A'

 enum A{a=170141183460469231731687303715884105727,b=-1};

                                                      ^

main.cpp:5:8: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

 enum A{a=170141183460469231731687303715884105727,b=-1};
```

Take a look at the last one. If it's truncated to an unsigned type, that explains by there is a compiler error (because b is -1). For example #2, the truncation [doesn't seem to happen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/354fd7c65a21d590).

Comment: See my update, I know that it works on Coliru, because that's a different machine, which will have the same behaviour if you change the value of `a` to it's to pow(2,127)-1 , http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a00e30f52e91378

Comment: @AlexDan Maybe it's different in C++11? I don't think it's related to the machine, but rather what standard mode you compile in.

Comment: I didn't use c++11, it's c++4.8

Comment: @AlexDan What I'm saying is the error happens in C++03 mode but not C++11 mode. Therefore I suspect the behavior is different somehow.

Comment: do you know why ? since c++11 gives errors in both cases, which to me is the logical behavior, is this bug in c++03 or do you have any explaination

Comment: @AlexDan I have no idea if it's related to enums or just implicit conversions in general. Someone with more standardese than me will have to come along and provide an answer.